# The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to navigate to another screen from the first one, so basically, I'm checking if the user is logged in or not and based on that I navigate or not to the next screen, but I'm getting an error of a context while trying that

This is my code

```dart
Future _AuthenticateUser(BuildContext context){
  FirebaseAuth.instance
      .authStateChanges()
      .listen((event) {
      if(event == null){
      // User is null
     } else {

        // here I navigate to the next screen
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MainScreen()));

    }
  });
}
```

I'm calling the code at first to check for user logging state

```dart
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _AuthenticateUser(context);
    super.didChangeDependencies();

  }
```

This is the error i'm getting

```
The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

Answer (score 0):

First lets know why we get this error..

```
static Future<T> push<T extends Object>(BuildContext context, Route<T> route) {
  return Navigator.of(context).push(route);
}
```

the above push function "push" search for the navigator in the context and push your screen on it so what i can conclude is that you need to check if the parents have navigator or not....